# How to unfold a single column with R dataframe/data.table,

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following R data.table (though I'm happy to work with a dataframe for this small dataset)

```
library(data.table)

dt = readcsv(...)
head(dt)

   column1 column2  column3  column4    column5   column6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 1     5   456421   437141 1.044105     32935      893562                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 2    42   756152   714126 1.058850     45913     1470278                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 3    36   157817   150205 1.050677     14558      308022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 4    20   181700   172716 1.052016     15077      354416
```

I would like to merge `column2` and `column3` into one column, keeping all of their associated rows, and using a binary label to keep track of where these values originally came from. The data.table I have in mind is in the following format:

```
   column1 combined column4   column5   column6   from_column_2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 1     5   456421   1.044105  32935      893562   TRUE
 2     5   437141   1.044105  32935      893562   FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 3    42   756152   1.058850  45913     1470278   TRUE
 4    42   714126   1.058850  45913     1470278   FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 5    36   157817   1.050677  14558      308022   TRUE
 6    36   150205   1.050677  14558      308022   FALSE                                                                                                                                            
 ....
```

I'm very confused how one would do this with data.table. Most operations are "table-wide". As for using `dplyr` or `tidyr`, I'm not sure how I'm filtering anything...

Comment: have you tried `?melt` i.e. `melt(dt, measure.vars =  c("column2", "column3"))`

Comment: The `tidyr` solution would be `df <- gather(df, key = source.column, value = combined, column2, column3)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus This is excellent, thanks! Is there a way to execute this code without having to re-define `variable` and `values` afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement this as:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = read_csv(...)

df %>%
  gather(from_col, combined, column2, column3) %>%
  mutate(from_column_2 = ifelse(from_col == "column2", T, F))
```

Best of luck!